# Undefined variable notices in PHP class instance call

Tags: php, debugging

Using PHP, when I call an instance of a class I am getting an undefined variable notice back. I program in other languages, but am less familiar with PHP, can you please look at my code and inform me as to my mistake in defining my class variables? Thanks.

```
<?php
    // create class Bike
    class Bike
    {
        // create variables for class Bike of price, max_speed, and miles
        var $price;
        var $max_speed;
        var $miles;

        // create constructor for class Bike with user set price and max_speed
        function __construct($price, $max_speed)
        {
            $this->price = $price;
            $this->max_speed = $max_speed;
        }

        // METHODS for class Bike:
        // displayInfo() - have this method display the bike's price, maximum speed, and the total miles driven
        function displayInfo()
        {
            echo "Price: $" . $price .  "<p>Maximum Speed: " . $max_speed . "</p>" . "<p>Total Miles Driven: " . $miles . "</p>";
        }

        // drive() - have it display "Driving" on the screen and increase the total miles driven by 10
        function drive()
        {
            $miles = $miles + 10;
            echo "<p>Driving!</p>" . "<p>Total Miles Driven: " . $miles . "</p>";
        }

        // reverse() - have it display "Reversing" on the screen and decrease the total miles driven by 5...
        function reverse()
        {
            // What would you do to prevent the instance from having negative miles?
            if($miles >= 5)
            {
                $miles = $miles - 5;
                echo "<p>Reversing</p><p>Total Miles Driven: " . $miles . "</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>Total Miles Driven is less than 5 miles, unable to reverse!</p>";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    // Create 3 bike object class instances
    $Schwinn = new Bike(50, '10mph');
    $Specialized = new Bike(500, '25mph');
    $Cannondale = new Bike(1000, '50mph');

    // Have the first instance drive three times, reverse one and have it displayInfo().
    var_dump($Schwinn); // shows instance is created with proper variable assignments
    $Schwinn -> drive();
    // $Schwinn -> drive();
    // $Schwinn -> drive();
    $Schwinn -> reverse();
    $Schwinn -> displayInfo();
?>
```

Errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: miles in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 27
>   Notice: Undefined variable: miles in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 35
>   Notice: Undefined variable: price in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 21
>   Notice: Undefined variable: max_speed in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 21
>   Notice: Undefined variable: miles in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 21

Comment: What is the message that you're getting when you run this?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: miles in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined variable: miles in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined variable: price in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: max_speed in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: miles in /home/heidi/Desktop/CodingDojo/OOP/php_oop_basic1.php on line 21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP (and in javascript, python and many others), `$this` is explicit when referencing class variables:

```
// local variable
$price
// class variable
$this->price
```

Also take a look at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: It's not bad AT ALL. `$price` by itself would simply be a local variable within the method. Utterly common practice. The problem is that the OP's trying to use them as globals and `$price` is not defined within that method's scope, hence the errors/warnings.

Comment: I meant this is bad for accessing a class variable. I've changed `bad` to `local variable`.

Answer (score 2):

Every instance you try to assign the variables (properties) of an object you need to use `$this->var_name`. Your code should be updated to read like this:

```
<?php
    // create class Bike
    class Bike
    {
        // create variables for class Bike of price, max_speed, and miles
        var $price;
        var $max_speed;
        var $miles;

        // create constructor for class Bike with user set price and max_speed
        function __construct($price, $max_speed)
        {
            $this->price = $price;
            $this->max_speed = $max_speed;
        }

        // METHODS for class Bike:
        // displayInfo() - have this method display the bike's price, maximum speed, and the total miles driven
        function displayInfo()
        {
            echo "Price: $" . $this->price .  "<p>Maximum Speed: " . $this->max_speed . "</p>" . "<p>Total Miles Driven: " . $this->miles . "</p>";
        }

        // drive() - have it display "Driving" on the screen and increase the total miles driven by 10
        function drive()
        {
            $this->miles = $this->miles + 10;
            echo "<p>Driving!</p>" . "<p>Total Miles Driven: " . $this->miles . "</p>";
        }

        // reverse() - have it display "Reversing" on the screen and decrease the total miles driven by 5...
        function reverse()
        {
            // What would you do to prevent the instance from having negative miles?
            if($this->miles >= 5)
            {
                $this->miles = $this->miles - 5;
                echo "<p>Reversing</p><p>Total Miles Driven: " . $this->miles . "</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>Total Miles Driven is less than 5 miles, unable to reverse!</p>";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    // Create 3 bike object class instances
    $Schwinn = new Bike(50, '10mph');
    $Specialized = new Bike(500, '25mph');
    $Cannondale = new Bike(1000, '50mph');

    // Have the first instance drive three times, reverse one and have it displayInfo().
    var_dump($Schwinn); // shows instance is created with proper variable assignments
    $Schwinn -> drive();
    // $Schwinn -> drive();
    // $Schwinn -> drive();
    $Schwinn -> reverse();
    $Schwinn -> displayInfo();
?>
```

This Outputs:

```
object(Bike)#1 (3) { ["price"]=> int(50) ["max_speed"]=> string(5) "10mph" ["miles"]=> NULL }

Driving!

Total Miles Driven: 10

Reversing

Total Miles Driven: 5
Price: $50

Maximum Speed: 10mph

Total Miles Driven: 5
```

Also, look into defining property and method [Visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). Defining properties with `var` in an object assumes it's set in "public" visibility scope. Examples:

```
class Bike
{
    var $price; //var was almost depreciated in objects (early PHP 5.0)

    public $price; //Now the commonly accepted method, same behavior as above.

    protected $price; //protected means only this class, parent class or extended class can use this $price

    private $price; //Private means only this class may use this $price property.

    public $price = ''; //You can also define the variable when declaring it.
```

You can also declare methods (class functions) with the same visibility scopes. Also, you can only get public properties (object variables) outside of the class definition using `$class->var_name`. Private and protected properties will throw a fatal error as they cannot be accessed directly.