# PHP getter setter throwing undefined Variable Notice

Tags: php

I have this class:

```
<?php
namespace Discord\OAuth;

class DefaultScopes {

  public $defaultScopes = [];

  public function getDefaultScopes() {
    return $this->$defaultScopes;
  }

  public function setDefaultScopes($array) {
    $this->$defaultScopes = $array;
  }
}
```

Then I initialize it with `setDefaultScopes(['bot']);` .

And when I try to get the array with `getDefaultScopes()` I get an Error saying that the Variable may not have been initialized.

Comment: it's `$this->defaultScopes` without `$`

Comment: Try to use getDefaultScopes and surround them with try

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388303/undefined-variable-notices-in-php-class-instance-call

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dollar sign after the `$this`.

```
<?php
namespace Discord\OAuth;

class DefaultScopes {

  public $defaultScopes = [];

  public function getDefaultScopes() {
    return $this->defaultScopes;
    //           ^^ 
  }

  public function setDefaultScopes($array) {
    $this->defaultScopes = $array;
    //    ^^  
  }
}
```

Btw, avoid keeping your property public.

Comment: This question should not be answered based on [StackOverflow's "Answering" page in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).' (As it is a duplicate)

Comment: It was marked as duplicate the instant I posted the answer.

Comment: @RafikTighilt actually this question was ask a lot of time, and anyway just a comment will be totally usefull for this kind of asking